# javascript to display div element based on a calculated value

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display a different div elements based on a calculated value, basically

```
if(x <= total){display y <div>} else {display z <div>}
```

I cannot figure out what part of the div I need to capture to display the div, right now my conditional statement doesn't work, it only shows the div after the button is pushed.  The var surlyValue is being set properly.  Here is the HTML for the button

```
<button type="button" onclick="show('fixingSteps');">What Do I Need To Do?</button>
```

This is the HTML for the 2 options

```
<div class="side-by-side" id="fixingSteps" name="fixingSteps" style="background: aquamarine; display: none">
            <h1>Recommended Mitigations</h1>
            <div> Smile, Everyone Should Be Happy, No Mitigations are Neccessary!!!!</div>
        </div>

        <div class="side-by-side" id="fixingSteps" name="fixingSteps1" style="background: aquamarine; display: none">
            <h1>Recommended Mitigations</h1>
            <div>
                <select id="mitS" name='mitS' onchange="calculateTotalWithMitigation()">
                    <option value="none">Select Input</option>
                    <option value="mit1">Mitigation 1</option>
                    <option value="mit2">Mitigation 2</option>
                    <option value="mit3">Mitigation 3</option>
                    <option value="mit4">Mitigation 4</option>
                    <option value="mit5">Mitigation 5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

And this the the JS function I am trying to use

```
function show(elementId) {

var surlyValue = getValue();

if (surlyValue < 10) {
    document.getElementById("fixingSteps").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(elementId).style.display = "block";
} else {
    document.getElementsByName("fixingSteps1").style.display = "block";
}
}
```

Thanks for helping me learn how to use JS on this example

Comment: This only happens after the button is clicked because your function is called in the `onclick=` attribute. Are you wanting this to happen on page load?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're asking - what is the behavior you expect and how does that differ from what you're wanting?

Comment: 1. There's no element with id `mitigationSteps`, 2. Why `.getElementsByName("fixingSteps1").style` (which won't work because `.getElementsByName()` returns a list of elements) in the `else` branch instead of `.getElementById("fixingSteps")` as in the `if` branch?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] using the stack snippet and explain exactly what is wrong with it - your question isn't very clear and you talk about and show elements that aren't in the code you've shown. Also why name your input different to your id - it is confusing, especially as you are using 2 different ways of getting the element in your js - consistency is key to maintainable code

Comment: I am trying to show a list of steps to help fix a problem when a button is pressed based on a calculation from a user input.  I Andreas comment about `mitigationSteps`.  The issue I am having is that no matter the value of surlyValue the code always displays the same `div` I would like to display a different `div` with different options if surlyValue is higher or lower, if that makes sense